# Knockoutjs customBinding text base on language

Tags: javascript, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

In all my models i have at least 2 Observable properties that i use for language (display base on it)

```
this.id = data.id;
this.DataNameEn = ko.protectedObservable(cuberryItem.DataNameEn);//this prop ends with En
this.DataNameDe = ko.protectedObservable(cuberryItem.DataNameDe);//this prop ends with De
this.DataValue = ko.protectedObservable(cuberryItem.DataValue);
```

I need to create a custom binding so when some global variable example is 'en' than will be display the **DataNameEn** when other language then **DataNameDe**, first i did try it with computed but it don't fill right to do it for every ViewModel.
How can i archive this with bindings or is better to leave with computed observable.

THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with the computed observable, if you dont want to do it for all your models then you can use inheritance, and create a class named like Localizable and then all your viewmodels would inherit from this class.

Here is an article on using inheritance using jquery http://davidjs.com/2011/07/jquery-extend-inheritance/, however if you have decent javascript knowledge you should better do it without jquery.